# How to get TeamCity Build trigger filter to build feature branches but not default branch

Tags: git, teamcity, teamcity-9.0

I've created a Team City build to build the feature branches:

Default Branch: refs/heads/development
Branch Specification: refs/heads/feature/*

I have a vcs trigger so it builds for every git push. But I don't want it to build when someone pushes to the development branch.

I have tried playing with the branch filter in the trigger, but either features and development build on push, or none of them do.

I'm using TC 9.1.1

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try the following settings:
Default Branch: refs/heads/development
Branch Specification: +:refs/heads/feature/*

VCS trigger branch filter:

```
+:*  
-:<default>
```

Comment: Yes, that did it. I'd tried the -:&lt;default&gt; on it's own, but not the +:*. Thank you

Comment: Is `<default>` meant to be written verbatim, or should i put in for instance `-:/refs/heads/development`?

Comment: Would be helpful to support explicit path/branch triggers than having to rely on explicit exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

We are using TC 2017.2 and had the same problem.
We could disable the automatic triggering, but you could still start it by hand, which is annoying as it will keep a build agent occupied for nothing.

Then we found out we have the option to disable the actual build of a feature branch.
If you go to `Version Control Settings` there is a `Default Branch Settings` section.

More info [here](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD18/Configuring+VCS+Settings#ConfiguringVCSSettings-DisableBuildinginDefaultBranch)