# Is possible to use multiple branch specification in TeamCity using TFS Git features?

Tags: tfs, teamcity, feature-branch

In my project we use feature branches with **TFS 2013** as source control repository and **TeamCity 9.1.6** as CI server. We have plans to upgrade to TFS 2015 soon (... and cannot migrate to GIT)

I know you can use [multiple branch specification](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Working+with+Feature+Branches) when you use GIT or Mercurial... and it is pretty useful. In TFS 2013, Microsoft added native support for GIT.

[image: multiple branch specification picture]

**I want to do multiple branch specification using my existing TFS server**, in order to have a single commit build that builds every feature branch.

**So my questions are:**

1. Is there any TeamCity plugin that allow me to do that? (Easier than my possible GIT-TFS trick)
2. Given that TFS 2013 has GIT support, can I configure my VCS to make TeamCity build think TFS is a GIT server and use multiple branch specification as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32631949/how-to-get-teamcity-build-trigger-filter-to-build-feature-branches-but-not-defau)?

In theory TeamCity VCS connecting to TFS as a GIT server will think it is a GT server, won't it?

Answer (score 1):

No additional plugin is needed.
You can configure Git connection in TeamCity to Git repository hosted in Team Foundation Server 2013. The type of repository will be "Git" in TeamCity, so all git-related features (such as branches) will be supported.

Comment: Is it possible to configure an existing TFS server to be also accessed as a a GIT server? (Or, as I am afraid ,you should choose at TFS installation)

Answer (score 1):

TFS 2013 provides the option to use either TFVC or Git for your source control repository. When you create a team project, select Git from the version control options:

[image]

More information of using Git, please check: 
https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/git/get-started

Comment: My problem is that team project already exists as TFVC. I am afraid is        not possible but ideally all the devs should still access it as TFVC and my TeamCity access it as Git (in order to have multiple branch specification)

Comment: You can consider migrating a TFVC team project to a Git team project. Check: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tfssetup/2015/05/19/migrating-a-tfvc-team-project-to-a-git-team-project-along-with-changeset-history-in-tfs/